# How to create a background image that is fit to height with blurred backdrop behind it

Tags: css

Is there any way to create a `background-image` that is fit to height with a blurred backdrop behind it using CSS? I'll use js if I have to (but don't want to).

**Example:**
[image: example]

Comment: Yes sure! What did you try so far and where did it fail? If you haven't already, make sure you check out the `object-fit` property and the `blur()` function of the `filter` property.

Comment: @agrm `object-fit` is for `<img>`s and `<video>`s isn't it? I am working with a `<div>` with a `background-image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it in many ways, but it will always require two images: one behind it blurred and another one on top.

**Solution with just CSS (background-image) based on pseudo classes before/after :**

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_bunny_small.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain ;
}

.container:before {
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

**Solution with two images :**

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_bunny_small.jpg" class="bg" />
  <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_bunny_small.jpg" class="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Woah, I was just making an answer with background image and `<img>` when I saw your answer. Great job on thinking about pseudo-elements!

Comment: @Vepthy <img> solution is still worth considering, so I've added this

Comment: That's more like it :) ! Great one. Also, first option is with pseudo **elements**, not classes

Comment: Nice one. Just want to add you also have the [`backdrop-filter`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/) property, although it's still not supported in Firefox